# how to Insert the multiple result of a CTE into a table?

Tags: postgresql, insert, common-table-expression

I am trying to insert a result of a CTE

these are my two tables:

```
reate table account(
accountid bigint primary key,
customerid bigint not null,
description varchar(50),
foreign key (customerid) references customer(customerid));

create table transaction(
transactionid bigint primary key,
accountid bigint not null,
trantimestamp timestamp not null,
amount numeric(8,2) not null,
foreign key (accountid) references account(accountid));
```

and this is the insert statement that will insert the result of the CTE:

```
insert into transaction (accountid, trantimestamp, amount) 
with accounts as(select accountid, sum(amount)amounts from transaction where accountid in(
select accountid from account where description ='saving' order by accountid) group by accountid order by accountid)
select accountid, now(), (0.01*amounts)/100 from accounts;
```

I was not able to insert multiple lines into the table. 
I know that the first line is inserted, and then it doesn't insert because of the primarykey that stays stuck in the first line updated .

I also tried the function "returning transactionid" . but it is not working either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `transactionid` is not in the list of inserted columns, your statement will implicitly try to insert NULL into this column. That won't work because a primary key is automatically `NOT NULL`.

If you want the column to be filled with increasing numbers automatically, define it as `bigserial`. That will set a `DEFAULT` that is generated with a sequence.